# run two node application at same time with different port

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two node application  use port 3000 and 5000.When i run it on localhost it run without any error.but when run two at same time with two different terminal last one remain executed and first one destroy session and redirect to login page when click on any page.After that when click on last one any page they also lost session and redirect to login.I want two application run at time.

This is session and port of admin app

```
 admin.use(session({
    secret : 'ssshhhhh',
    proxy : true,
    resave : true,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));


admin.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
var debug = require('debug')('Admin App');
var server = admin.listen(admin.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

and This  is for user app

```
app.use(session({
    secret : 'ssshhhhh',
    proxy : true,
    resave : true,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var debug = require('debug')('User App');
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Could you print `process.env.PORT` for both in both case?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but if the `PORT` env variable is set, both apps will run in the same port, so this may be your problem here

Comment: process.env.PORT print undefined.i also try by removing process.env.port still not working

Comment: when i run second application first one logged out

Comment: I'm facing the exact problem. And removing process.env.port is not working either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I figured out the root cause, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your session options. For both admin and user app, there is no session name defined in options. So, a default session_name will be used which will be same for both apps. Hence, the session is going for toss when run simultaneously.

To resolve this, add a unique name option to session object as shown below:

```
admin.use(session({
    name: 'admin_cookie',
    secret : 'ssshhhhh',
    proxy : true,
    resave : true,
    saveUninitialized : true
}));

app.use(session({
   name: 'user_cookie',
   secret : 'ssshhhhh',
   proxy : true,
   resave : true,
   saveUninitialized : true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found thus far is to use the package called concurrently:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

package.json config as follows works for me:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore client",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  }
```